# Styling from another component which is being imported doesn't apply Vue3

Tags: javascript, css, sass, vuejs3

I'm attempting to import my form radio buttons while setting styles for the radio buttons and labels. I'm wondering why the styling isn't taking effect for ComponentA.vue.

ComponentA.vue

```
<template>
  <form method="get" novalidate>
    <fieldset>
      <div class="radio-group">
        <form-radio-buttons>
          <div class="radio-option">
            <input 
              id="input-item"
              ...
            />
            <label class="radio-label" for="input-item">
              <div class="radio-content">
                <h5 class="radio-heading">
                  Title Here
                </h5>
                <p class="radio-details">
                  Description Here
                </p>
              </div>
            </label>
          </div>
        </form-radio-buttons>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</template>
```

FormRadioButtons.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="radio-item">
    <slot />
    <slot name="error" />
  </div>
</template>

<style lang="scss">

 .radio-group input[type="checkbox"]:checked.radio-option label:after {
   background: $form-radio-buttons-active-color;
 }

 .radio-group input[type="checkbox"]:checked.radio-option label:before{
   border-color: $form-radio-buttons-active-color;
 }

.radio-group .radio-label .radio-content::before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

:slotted(.radio-group .radio-label) {
   ::after {
     border-radius: 50%;
     content: '';
     transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
     display: block;
     position: absolute;
     transform: translate(50%, 50%);
     height: 0.5em;
     width: 0.5em;
     left: 0;
     top: 0.25em;
   }
}

span {
   display: inline-block;

   &:not(:last-child) {
     margin-right: 1em;
   }
 }

 .radio-item {
   margin-bottom: 1em;

  @include breakpoint(md) {
     margin-bottom: 1.25em;
   }
 }
</style>
```

I have tried using the `:global` or `:slotted` but it seems that the `::before` pseudo doesn't work. I'm wondering now if there's something wrong with the way I use the global and slotted